# What to do with an old external drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive

This is a weird question because people usually want to know how to turn an internal drive into an external, but I want the opposite.

I have two external 500GB HDDs that I can't really use anymore because I have too much data.  So basically at this point they are combined a third backup of only 1TB of my data.  I don't know if this is possible, but **can I take the drive out of its external enclosure and put it into my desktop**?  That way I can maybe RAID it, or I was thinking about just using it to install another OS.

They are both MicroNet PlatinumXL's and the specs are:

Drive Mechanisms: 7200RPM, 16MB Cache ATA6
BUS Speed: Up to 80MB/S
Interface Ports: 2x9pin FireWire 800, and 1x6 pin FireWire 400

I think the only thing useful up there is that its an ATA6, but i put the rest down just incase...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can put this drive in a desktop system.  An [ATA-6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA#Current_terminology) drive is a Parallel ATA interface with 100MB/s transfer rate.

Similarly, you could buy a new ATA-6 drive an put it in the external enclosure for a larger external drive.

Comment: Ah, good idea, i just might do that!

Answer (score 3):

Extra drives are always best used for some form of backup. The key is assigning the right type of backup to them. If you find yourself with extra drives and drive space, the best thing to do is always upgrade your level of backup.

Consider the following:

1. Use as dedicated storage for system images or snapshot backups.
2. Use as redundant storage for priceless data (synched on a schedule)
3. Use as data caches located off-site for easy access and/or disaster-proof redundant storage.

Finally, you can always just put a lot of data on them, then throw them in your attic as time capsules.

Comment: thanks, but i still want to know if i can take the drive out of its enclosure and put it into my desktop?

Comment: As long as the drive inside the enclosure is a standard SATA drive (which it usually is), you should be able to rip it out and use it internally in a computer. If you can unscrew your enclosure it might be worth a look-see. Note that you might have to permanently break the enclosure to get the drive out (i.e. rip out the internal connectors).